# MySQL - Get all string sizes stored in a field

Tags: mysql, string

I would like to get all string sizes that are stored in a field `myfield` which is a varchar(128), along with their occurrences (i.e. the number of rows with that specific length). This is what I have so far:

```
MySQL > SELECT SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(myfield)=5) as occurr from mytable;
+--------+
| occurr |
+--------+
|   9194 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.39 sec) 

MySQL > SELECT SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(myfield)=6) as occurr from mytable;
+--------+
| occurr |
+--------+
|  11636 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.44 sec)  

MySQL > SELECT SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(myfield)=7) as occurr from mytable;
+--------+
| occurr |
+--------+
|  19022 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.48 sec)
```

Is there a way to get this data with a single SQL command? Something like this output:

```
+--------+--------+
| length | occurr |
+--------+--------+
|      5 |   9194 |
+--------+--------+
|      6 |  11636 |
+--------+--------+
|      7 |  19022 |
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(myfield) AS length, COUNT(*) AS occurr
FROM mytable
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(myfield) IN (5,6,7)
GROUP BY CHAR_LENGTH(myfield)
```

You can, of course, remove the `WHERE` clause, if you are not interested in some specific character lengths.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(my_field) AS`length`, COUNT(*) AS`occurr`FROM`mytable`GROUP BY CHAR_LENGTH(my_field)`

I was still typing as the other answer came up. Basically the same - except no limit on what CHAR_LENGTH() is included.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(myfield) as length, COUNT(*) as occurence FROM mytable WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(myfield) BETWEEN 4 and 6 GROUP BY length
```

edit: I posted this more or less simultaniously to the identical answers above. I did of course not intend to steal an answer.